# Filtering in RailsAdmin using integer field of a belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I'm attempting to configure "fields searching" on my `User` model using RailsAdmin and a `belongs_to` association, called `Budget`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :budget
end

class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

The `Budget` object has a field `price_in_dollars` of type `Integer`.

In RailsAdmin, viewing the `Budget` object, I can click "Add filter" and choose "Price in dollars", which allows filtering using "Number" or "Between ... and ...", specifying a range.

I want to use similar filtering on my `User` model to filter by `Budget`, using the `price_in_dollars` column.

The [RailsAdmin List documentation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List#fields-searching) states:

> Belongs_to associations:
>
> - will be searched on their foreign_key (:team_id)
> - or on their label if label is not virtual (:name, :title, etc.)
> - you can also specify columns on the targeted table or the source table

Based on this, I added this block to my `User` model:

```
rails_admin do
  list do
    field :budget do
      searchable [:price_in_dollars]
    end
  end
end
```

With this block, I can now enter a value such as "500" and filter using "contains" or "is exactly", and the `price_in_dollars` column is used, rather than the foreign key ID.

However, I do not have the ability to filter by a range, as I do when going to the `Budget` admin page directly.

Is there a way to force the filtering menu to use the options specific to a number or integer? It appears that it may be treating it like a string data type regarding filtering.

Comment: did you find solution to this?

Comment: @Zahid, no, unfortunately I did not. I suspect this is not currently possible, but it may be worth posting to their [mailing list](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#getting-help) to ask about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search integer values of a belongs_to association like this

```
  field :budget, :integer do
    label 'Price in dollars'
    queryable true
    pretty_value do
      bindings[:object].budget.price_in_dollars
    end        
    searchable [{Budget => :price_in_dollars}]
  end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to get this project back up and running to thoroughly test this answer (though not for lack or trying), but after reviewing the docs this does appear to be the correct solution.

Relevant documentation is here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List#fields-searching